# UNLINK not working on windows 7 localhost wamp. Working fine on live site

Tags: php, file-upload, permission-denied

I am developing a site on localhost and uploading it on live as well. The problem is that the code is working fine on live but giving this error on localhost. Permisison denied. I have went through every possible answer but couldn't find the solution. Help please.

[image]

Comment: Check readonly permissions on the file, if it's one you are creating chmod the file

Comment: Yes chmod is being created. If I delete any other file than `.zip`, it is deleted successfully. Just `.zip` is not being deleted.